# Mailed Equipment to Employer after Leaving Company?

Tags: equipment

I amicably parted ways with a company.

The tracking receipt shows that the package was delivered to the mailing address on the label I received from the employer. I haven't yet received an acknowledge from them that equipment has been received.

Am I responsible for the equipment at any point now?

Comment: The chances are that they'd let you know if they _didn't_ receive it.

Comment: Tip: In the future, if you have to mail it back as opposed to hand-carrying it in, use Registered Mail.  You got lucky this time: the Post Awful did actually deliver the package, as opposed to losing it somewhere.  (I've seen them lose packages.  I've also seen what looked a whole lot like a postal employee trying to steal a package, and giving up when the package trace showed it had gotten to his small post office and no farther.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have proof that it was delivered, I would assume everything's done and you don't need to follow up on it or worry about it - If they have any questions they'll likely reach out;

It's possible that they're so busy that they forgot to - or perhaps would feel awkward about - reach out to you letting you know it was delivered

Comment: I have a tracking number that shows it was delivered when I feed the tracking number into the delivery service's site. Is that enough proof?

Comment: The tracking number proves that something was delivered to the employer. Doesn't prove what was delivered.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie So you wouldn't tell the company that you have a tracking number. If they take you to court claiming they received nothing you show your tracking number and prove them wrong. They'd have to make a claim that they received some bricks for example, and if you received that, you would act immediately.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, in that specific circumstance it can be used to show the company is lying.

Comment: A company would reach out multiple times if they didn't receive it, long before taking you to court, and likely wouldn't go to court regardless - its an expensive process and likely wouldn't be worth it for a device with an actual cash value of, say, 500-900 bucks. Phone calls are cheap/free, attorneys cost hundreds per hour, if they were missing the device you would be HEARING about it quite a bit I believe :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have piece of mind, you should send your old employer an email, asking them to verify that they have received all outstanding equipment.

> Dear [Contact X],
>
> I have shipped all outstanding equipment to [Employer Y] and have have received notification it has been delivered.
>
> Are you able to confirm that all equipment is accounted for and there is nothing else outstanding?
>
> Kind regards, qu7869069

You are responsible for the equipment until it is back in possession of the employer. Unless the employer engaged the shipping company themselves, you are responsible to make sure that happens. So it doesn't hurt to get a confirmation email from the employer that everything has been delivered.